# How do I create a conditional clause for firestore.collection.doc(id).delete()

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I have an ionic page that has a list of items.  When I delete an item I have to leave the page and come back to see the item is removed.  I can search through the array for the item to delete it I don't know how delete based on a condition.

```js
async removeItinerary(id) {
      const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      header: 'Albums',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Delete',
          role: 'destructive',
          icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'trash' : null,
          handler: () => {
            return this.itineraryCollection.doc(id).delete();
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel', // will always sort to be on the bottom
          icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'close' : null,
          handler: () => {
          }
        }
            ]
        });
        await actionSheet.present();
    }
```

And I'm calling it from the component:

```js
  deleteItinerary(id: string) {
    this.dataSvc.removeItinerary(id);
  }
```

So the problem is if a user click's cancel I don't want to remove the item from the collection.  But if they click delete I want to remove the item from the array.  What's the best way to do that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's the condition, Checking ID ? and please post the code for this.dataSvc

Comment: The data service code is the one above "removeItinerary".  It's returning this.itineraryCollection.doc(id).delete();

Comment: I don't know what this.itineraryCollection.doc(id).delete(); is returning to the calling method.  The condition would be the user selected 'Delete' on the ActionSheet and NOT 'Cancel'.

Comment: The delete function doesn't need to return anything

Comment: So how do I handle this?  It's not returning anything so how do I know if the user clicked cancel or delete? If they clicked delete I need to remove the item from the array but only when they click delete

Comment: There are handlers for each button, and you have written the delete operation in the "Delete" one, not the "Cancel"